# Разность первого и последнего значения между дат

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT house.name, point.id, rw.data

FROM Unit AS city

    JOIN Unit AS street ON street.ParentID = city.UnitID
    JOIN Unit AS house ON house.ParentID = street.UnitID

    JOIN Points AS point ON point.ID = house.UnitID

    JOIN Data AS rw ON rw.DevID = point.DevID
    AND rw.Time BETWEEN '20161209' AND '20161211'

WHERE city.id = 1
```

Получаю улицу, затем номер дома, а после id устройства, привязанного к дому. С устройства, между датами за 3 дня, получаю 3 записи float значений.

Как получить разность значений (rw.Value) 11 и 9 числа, и поместить её в rw.data?

Comment: Бьюсь уже несколько дней с запросом. Буду признателен за помощь и развёрнутый ответ

Comment: Покажите запрос на создание таблицы, пример исходных данных и пример ожидаемого результата. Это существенно ускорит поиск решения.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, таблица была создана сторонним ПО. Данные отображаются в виде "Улица, Дом, Значение (rw.Value)" по 3 записи на один и тот же дом, то есть сам промежуток дат за каждое число. Мне нужно из диапазона взять последнюю запись и вычесть из неё первую. То есть вместо диапазона и трёх записей мне нужна одна запись одного дома

Comment: Возьмите запись за среднюю дату и посчитайте для неё LEAD(value)-LAG(value)... :)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, визуально выглядит [так](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ag2Q.png). 2 дома, по 3 записи

Comment: Что делать если за 11 записи не окажется, а только за 9 и 10 ? Т.е. достаточно ли из последнего значения (`last_value()`) вычесть первое (`first_value()`)

Comment: @Mike, да, вполне

Comment: А на выходе должна быть одна запись для каждого устройства, не 3 же ?

Comment: @Mike, Да, на скрине видно 3 записи одного дома за 3 дня, мне нужно из последнего дня вычесть первый

Comment: А float значение всегда растет или может уменьшаться и результат будет отрицательный ? (просто если всегда растет, то можно элементарный max()-min() сделать и на заморачиваться с оконными функциями)

Comment: @Mike, растёт с каждым днём, уменьшаться не может

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На основании измененной в коментариях постановки (значение поля всегда растет во времени):

```
SELECT house.name, point.id, max(rw.Value)-min(rw.Value)
  FROM Unit AS city
  JOIN Unit AS street ON street.ParentID = city.UnitID
  JOIN Unit AS house ON house.ParentID = street.UnitID
  JOIN Points AS point ON point.ID = house.UnitID
  JOIN Data AS rw ON rw.DevID = point.DevID
   AND rw.Time BETWEEN '20161209' AND '20161211'
 WHERE city.id = 1
 GROUP BY rw.DevID, house.name, point.id
```

Comment: Условия остались теми же. `Max` и `Min` без `GROUP BY`, как я понял, работать не будут. Лишь добавив некоторые переменные в `GROUP BY` у меня получилось что нужно. Можешь объяснить?

Comment: @Mr.Black Если `group by` не задано, то все группируется до одного общего итога. соответственно `min/max` берутся по всем выбранным устройствам, а не по каждому отдельно